# Exp notation and integration linear system

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, dynamical-systems, lie-derivative

In the case of a differential equation on the tangent space of a manifold (that is solutions are vector fields)
$$
\dot x = A(x)
$$
with the Cauchy condition $ x(t)=x_t$,
we often denote the solution at time $0$ as
$$
x(0;(t,x_t))=e^{-t\, \text{ad}\, A}(x_t).
$$

Then I saw the following expansion formula
$$
e^{-t\, A}(x_t)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-t)^k}{k!}\,\text{ad}^k A\cdot x_t ?
$$

*What is the ad operator ?*

It seems that in the first expression, it is just a notation but in the second, is it related to Lie brackets ? ...

Could you provide a reference where I could more details ?

---

To be more precise, here is what I read:

[image: ODE]
[image: Solution and Expansion]

So if you could provide me some books where I could find such ad-formula.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) should be helpful. That is, $\operatorname{ad} A ~ x\equiv [A,x]$. So, in your expansion formula, the *k*th term represents *k* nested commutators of *x* with *A*. It is a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma) formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, your convention is confusing/nonstandard (at least in physics and engineering).

The standard integration of linear diff eqn systems goes through [matrix exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equations) involving multiplication, not adjoint maps involving Lie commutators.

That is, 
$$
\dot x= A x \qquad \Longrightarrow x(t)= e^{tA} ~x_0 \qquad \Longrightarrow x(0)=x_0=e^{-tA} x_t, 
$$ 
and not an exponent involving commutators.

If you stick *x* along the diagonal of a square matrix with the dimension of *A*, call it *X*, then 
$$
\operatorname{ad}A ~ X \equiv [A,X], 
$$
and your expression 
$$
X(t)= e^{t\operatorname{ad}A} ~ X_0 = X_0+t[A,X_0]+t^2[A,[A,X_0]]/2!+ ... =e^{tA} X_0 e^{-tA} 
$$
indeed solves the matrix differential equation 
$$
\dot X= \operatorname{ad}A ~X = [A,X]
$$
*instead*, not quite your original differential equation! (Check it/prove it!).

Now, to be sure, if we operated these matrix equations on a vector in the kernel of *A*, they may formally be identified with your original one (check this!), but there is something missing or implicit in your layout...